# HIbernate query language problem

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `Project` class that has a `Set` of userstories called `userStories12many`.
I'm having troubles trying to get the project that has a certain userstory in its set `getComponent(int userStoryID)`

I think im on the right track but i dont know what i did wrong

```
public Projects getComponent(int userStoryID) {
    Session session = SessionFactoryHelper.getSessionFactory()
    .getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    List<Projects> compo = session.createQuery("select p "
    + "from Projects as p inner join fetch p.userStories12many as u "
    + "where u.storyId='" + userStoryID + "'").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return compo.get(0);

}
```

Comment: define "troubles". Are you getting an exception? If so, which one? Are you getting wrong results? Most bug reports I get from ordinary users are more clear than your question.

Comment: In your question you say you have a "Project" class, but in your example you have references to "Projects" class (plural of Project). Is this a typo or are you referring to two separate classes?

Comment: Creating hql queries by hand (string concat) is extremly error prone. I suggest using @NamedQuery. These will be checked for correctness, cached and are safer (no sql injection).

Comment: Hi, thank you guys for your comments. Here is the problem: Im new to HQL so i wanted to make sure that what i wrote was right to begin with. Is that how its done? The method is returning null. 

And yes there is only one class Project. I am aware im not using right ways of doing things but i just want to get this to work for the time being

Comment: Put some logging in to see how many Projects you are returning. If it wasn't returning any results you would get an IndexOutOfBoundsException on the get(0). Can you show the code that calls this method where the null is being found?

Comment: Im calling the line
System.out.println(getComponent(1).get(0).getName());
and its giving a null pointer

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thing that feel wrong to me in your code:

1. It's better to bind parameters rather than inserting their value directly in the query string.
2. How come the id is quoted? isn't it an int?
3. You are accessing the query results after the transaction is ended which is often a bad idea

Comment: Ive fixed your last two points but its still not working. It returning null.